# PHP: Unable to echo variable posted from python outside `if(isset($_POST['sign']))` block

Tags: php

I have searched almost everywhere read different documents but still I am unable to find answer of question which is **Why we can't use variable outside `if(isset($_POST['sign']))` block which posted from python?**
Consider this below code.

```
$sign = '';
if(isset($_POST['sign']))
{
    $sign = $_POST['sign'];
    
    if(!is_dir($sign))
    {
        mkdir($sign);
        echo "folder created";
    }
    else
    {
        echo "folder already exists";
    }
}
echo  $sign;
```

Here I am getting value coming from python in `$sign` it is working fine inside if block but when I echo it outside if block it is showing noting on browser.

Comment: Yes because the $sign is empty and the POST variable sign is empty so it will not assign the value in the $sign variable

Comment: @Jerson $sign is not empty it contains the value which i sent from python and as we can see in my code I am creating a folder with posted value my program is creating folder successfully so its mean $sign is not empty.

Comment: yes if you post a request the $_POST['sign'] has value, but if you visit in the browser, the REQUEST METHOD is not POST it is GET and also there is no value pass in the $_POST['sign'] so it will assign to $sign variable

Comment: @Jerson so what should I do when I need to use $sign outside if block or another if block in the same script?

Comment: If you want a value you send with one request (POST from your python script) available in a _totally different_ request (GET request, visiting the same URL in your browser) - then you need to _store_ it somewhere on the server.

Comment: @CBroe you mean I have to use SESSIONS?

Comment: Depends, on whether this data is associated with a specific user/client.

Comment: @CBroe I have already tried session but I am unable to access session variable outside that particular if block don't know why?

Comment: Don’t expect anyone to be able to tell you that, based on _that_ kind of problem description. You need to give us a proper problem description, and show & explain what exactly you are doing.

Comment: @CBroe I am asking a simple question that why we can't access any simple variable or session variable outside `if(isset($_POST['sign']))` block

Comment: That has already been explained - because you are apparently talking about two different requests here. (And for why it would not be working with sessions - again, you’d have to show us/explain what you actually did. I am guessing you started a session in your python-triggered request, but the client making the next request afterwards does not know the session id.)

Comment: @CBroe I am not talking about two different request kindly read my question again

Comment: That was what Jerson _guessed_ you must be doing here in one of the first comments, why did you not correct them then? So what _is_ the actual situation then? You make the python request, and directly in the response given _to_ the python script, you want to output the variable?

Comment: @CBroe I am sending data from python using post request in PHP and here in PHP I am creating folder by using that value which I have posted from python in PHP. till here everything is ok folder is created successfully but when I echo $sign outside if block nothing displayed. this is all scenario.

Comment: Sorry, but that is simply not reproducible with the code you have shown. Not if you are really only making _one_ request.

Comment: @CBroe what should I do?

Comment: We can’t reproduce the problem with the info given so far. Can you explicitly confirm that you are looking at the response for one and the same request? You make your request _from_ python, and then you show the response of the PHP script _in_ your python script as well?

Comment: @CBroe yes I am looking for one and the same request. My problem is I want to use the data coming from python outside if block in php script. **Why I am unable to access the data coming from python outside if(isset($_POST['sign'])) block?**

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/234769/discussion-between-programmer-and-cbroe).